# Class Initialization Error: Call to a member function on a non-object?

Tags: php

The model of my class is like this:

```
class Foo {
    private $date;
    public function set_date($date) {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    // ANSWER: this gets executed as a constructor (case-insensitive)
    public function foo() {
        print_r($this->date->format('Y'));
    }
}

$Foo = new Foo();
```

I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object` when calling `new Foo()`.

<strike>I have been unable to reproduce the error (the above code seems to work).</strike>

The above code is now an exact replica of the error.

Comment: Does your class have a __constructor?

Comment: No it doesn't. Do I have to construct the class with the date?

Comment: Is this the full class you're using or is it an exmple? You wrote "the above code seems to work", does that mean that this isn't the code that produces the error?

Comment: No. You don't need a constructor unless you need to initialize variables.

Comment: No, you don't need one - I was asking because you said it happens when you instantiate the class, which would indicate the constructor was attempting to do something. Does it extend a class which has a constructor?

Comment: Does your class have a method with the same name as the class (so `foo` in your example)?

Comment: Nope, it does not extend anything.

Comment: Maybe you called another method before `setDate()`?

Comment: Nope Voitcus, I did not.

Comment: it sounds as if the b() function would be invoked (since this may match the error message you get), because you invoke the format method on the Date property of your class (which may be null).

Comment: Please, don't use variable names that start with a capital letter.  Class names start with caps.

Comment: @Madbreaks woops, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error occurs when you create the class instance using `new Foo()` I would suspect that there is a method `foo()` in the class. Because there is no `__construct()` the method `foo()` is considered the constructor and gets executed. This could trigger the error, either directly or through calls to other methods.

Comment: Would have to be `function Foo()` (cap-F) would it not?

Comment: Not sure, let me just test that.

Comment: Capitalized or not, it will execute!

Comment: @Madbreaks: I just checked, even if the case does not match it's still considered the constructor.

Comment: And that's why it's important to post *real* code. If you would have run the code you originally posted in your question, then you probably  wouldn't have got this error.

Answer (score 4):

This is a syntax error:

```
print_r($this->Date->format('Y');
                              ^^^^  missing closing paren
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably other code that is executed. The method `format` is called in the method `b`.  `b` is not called in the code you gave, but it's probably called elsewhere, and before the date is set.

Comment: I now see @Madbreaks answer. He's right about the syntax errors, and maybe they fool the PHP parser, causing the format method to be executed as a separate statement. Fix the syntax errors first and only look for calls to `b` if the problem persists. :)